# phpunit test in lumen 5.5.2 not get json data with Request class

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, lumen

i use `lumen 5.5.2` and i wanna create http test for that.so i used this code:

```
class ExampleTest extends \TestCase
{
    public function testExample()
    {
        $header = [
         'access-token'  => '$2y$10$Z6PvDMkTVVaSQJD10YGEsOz6E2KdQ2Q9RKo7roanZIAwRz0thUoAS',
         'refresh-token' => '$2y$10$WA12Phc979GKN9xht89Fv.RSeaS/R4MErWTjLYY1mNC8vS03E84XC',
         'app-name'      => 'test',
         'app-secret'    => 'test',
         'Content-Type'  => 'application/json'
        ];

        $json=[
         "gdata"=>[
          "title"=>"testTitle",
          "slug"=>"testSlug",
          "tag"=>"testTag",
          "scope"=>1
         ]
        ];
        $this->json('POST', '/settings/gdata/create', $json, $header)->seeJson([ 'status' => true ]);
    }
}
```

But i can't get `$json` data with lumen `Request` and when i get that it's  null.